# Is there a way to start a Discovery client spring application even if the discovery server could not be contacted?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, consul

I have this microservice which is a discovery client:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I know that if it is tried to be started while the discovery server is not yet available, it will fail. I would like to know if there is a way to start the application even if the discovery server is still not available. The issue arose when I ran JUnit unit test for this during build. I am encountering the following stack trace snippet during startup/start of JUnit tests: (by the way, unit tests have nothing to do with service Discovery)

> 2016-03-07 14:45:54.741 ERROR 3024 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> **com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException**:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:80)
>   ~[consul-api-1.1.8.jar:na]    at
>   com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.makeGetRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:39)
>   ~[consul-api-1.1.8.jar:na]    at
>   com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:81)
>   ~[consul-api-1.1.8.jar:na]    at
>   com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValues(KeyValueConsulClient.java:150)
>   ~[consul-api-1.1.8.jar:na]    at
>   com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValues(KeyValueConsulClient.java:143)
>   ~[consul-api-1.1.8.jar:na]    at
>   com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.getKVValues(ConsulClient.java:394)
>   ~[consul-api-1.1.8.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySource.init(ConsulPropertySource.java:63)
>   ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-1.0.0.M6.jar:1.0.0.M6]   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:74)
>   ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-1.0.0.M6.jar:1.0.0.M6]   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
>   ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M5.jar:1.1.0.M5]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]     at ...

The discovery service is Consul.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue now. Apparently a fix has [been submitted](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/81).

Basically a retry was implemented.

Not sure how long until it makes into a release.

Honestly, I'm thinking of trying the Eureka option instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consul config can be turned off by setting this property to **false**: `spring.cloud.consul.enabled`

So I created a profile with this property and value. The profile is used when running unit test:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: unitTest
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: false
```